# I want to add data in Realtime database from android studio from the following code but it should not worked

Tags: java, android, xml

**Code for registration**

//Code used for inserting the data of students
I am not adding import parts because this question is not submitted at that time.

```
public class StudentregisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText stname;
    EditText stphone;
    EditText stemail;
    EditText stpassword;
    Button stbtn;


    DatabaseReference studentref;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.studentregister);

        stname=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        stemail=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress);
        stphone=findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        stpassword=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
        stbtn=findViewById(R.id.button7);

        studentref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students");

        stbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                
                InsertStudentData();

            }
        });
    }
    private void InsertStudentData(){

        String name=stname.getText().toString();
        String email=stemail.getText().toString();
        String phone=stphone.getText().toString();
        String password=stpassword.getText().toString();

        Students students=new Students(name,email,phone,password);

        studentref.push().setValue(students);
        Toast.makeText(StudentregisterActivity.this,"Register Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

**Students**

```
package com.example.pariksha;

public class Students {

    String name;
    String email;
    String phone;
    String password;

    public Students(String name, String email, String phone, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**setting-gradle**

//Gradle setting of the project

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.xyz.com" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Pariksha"
include ':app'
```

**gradle-properties**

//Gradle properties of the project

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**gradle-build app**

//Gradle properties of app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pariksha"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

}
```

**build gradle project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you changed rules for Firebase Realtime Database to allow everyone to read/write?

Comment: Yes I changed the rules to allow for read and write in Firebase Realtime Database. but How we know that the rules is changed for everyone or not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all please have a look at rules defined for Firebase Realtime Database.
If you're not using Firebase Auth, You can Update rules like this.

Goto **Realtime Database** then change tab to **Rules** and update rules.

```
{  
 "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Then you can write data.

```
private void InsertStudentData(){

    String name=stname.getText().toString();
    String email=stemail.getText().toString();
    String phone=stphone.getText().toString();
    String password=stpassword.getText().toString();

    Students students=new Students(name,email,phone,password);

    studentref.setValue(students).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
             Toast.makeText(StudentregisterActivity.this,"Register Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(StudentregisterActivity.this,"Register failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

One more thing..
You're using multiple dependencies, please change

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.2'
```

To

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

Comment: I need more information because when I made all changes in project but still the data would not insert in firebase Realtime database. Please help me

Comment: which toast is it showing ? Is it calling onSuccess or onFailure ?

Comment: When I click on submit button the there is no text appearing on the screen neither onSuccess nor onFailure.

Comment: have you added google-services.json file from Firebase?
Also update gradle-build app as i have added in  answer.

Comment: Yes I also added the google-service.json file in my project at right path. OK I will update the gradle build

Comment: Again there is no any action on clicking the submit button after upgrading the gradle build. Nithier it showing Register successfully nor Register failed

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure following things**

1. Internet permission in Manifest.
2. Set Firebase Realtime database Rules to Public/Authenticate user for private rules.
3. Internet Availability on testing device to push data into database.

**To set Internet Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**To set rules to public**

1. Goto Firebase console
2. Realtime database rules
3. Paste this code in rules

**

```
{
 “rules”: {
 “.read”: true,
 “.write”: true
 }
}
```

**

**At the end try uploading data using the code below**

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference tasksRef = rootRef.child("Students").push();
Students students=new Students(name,email,phone,password);
tasksRef.setValue(student);
```

Comment: I need more information because when I made all changes in project but still the data would not insert in firebase Realtime database. Please help me